# continuous functions from R to R with different topologies

Tags: general-topology

Is there any other continuous function  from R with standard topology to R with lower limit topology other than the constant function?
I can prove that no simple function (other than the constant one) is continuous.
But other functions I cannot prove. And I could not find it (if it exist).

Comment: It's late and I'm about to go to bed, so this may be completely wrong, but can't you do something with the fact that the continuous image of a connected set must be connected?  So the image of any interval in $R$ to $R^{LL}$ must be a connected subset of $R^{LL}$, and there aren't very many of those.

Comment: The identity function $R \to R^{LL}$ is not continuous. The identity function $R^{LL} \to R$ is continuous, though. You could postcompose any continuous function $R \to R$ or precompose any continuous function $R^{LL} \to R^{LL}$ to get more continuous functions $R^{LL} \to R$, but if you really want a non-constant continuous function $R \to R^{LL}$, it looks like more work is needed...

Answer (score 2):

Because $R_l$ is completely disconnected (clearly only one point  sets are connected) and continuous functions preserve connection, and $R$ is connected, the only continuous function can be the constant one

Answer (score 1):

I think this is right.
if f is continuous then
for any a and b
A=pre image of ([a,b[) is both open and closed.
this means that A is empty or whole of R.this implies the existence of one such a and b such that A=R.which would then imply that f is constant otherwise there would exist c and d such that pre image of ([c,d[) is neither empty nor the whole of R.